# Householder reflection with $u$=$x-y$

Tags: matrices

I am studying the following Householder reflection in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$H = I - 2 \frac{vv^t}{v^tv}$, with $v = x - y$ the result of subtracting any two different and non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I can see geometrically and by taking some examples that it seems to happen that $Hx = y$ and $Hy = x$, but I can't seem to be able to prove it for any pair of $x$ and $y$.

Does that property hold?

Comment: The reason you can’t prove it is because it doesn’t hold in general. Try $x=(2,0)^T$ and $y=(0,1)^T$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see. And how about for ||x|| = ||y||?

Comment: In that case, the reflector is the angle bisector of $x$ and $y$ so...

Comment: Right. I can see it geometrically, but I cannot seem to be able to write it as a proof.